# Override method Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to override the method: `authorize_endpoint_url` from the Gem in a Rails application: https://github.com/AzureAD/omniauth-azure-activedirectory/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/azure_activedirectory.rb

I tried to do it by adding a file to `config/initializers/oauth.rb`

With the code:

```
module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    # A strategy for authentication against Azure Active Directory.
    class AzureActiveDirectory
      def request_phase
        debugger
        "www.hans.com"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But this approach doesn't seem to work, nothing get's actually overwriten. What do I wrong? Thank you

Comment: Are you sure your code loads properly? You can check with `OmniAuth::Strategies::AzureActiveDirectory.instance_method(:request_phase).source_location` to see which one is used.

Comment: Hi @tadman thank you it was the loading, can you please write is as an answer so that I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing "monkey patch" style alterations you'll want to ensure they're loaded correctly. One way to test this is, after all is said and done, to interrogate Ruby to find out which method is actually being used:

```
OmniAuth::Strategies::AzureActiveDirectory.instance_method(:‌​request_phase).sourc‌​e_location
```

The `instance_method` call returns an object with information about that method and the `source_location` property tells you where that was defined.

If if's your method, great, you got it loaded right. If not you may need to check that you're hooking in at the correct time.